# What does a : mark in C mean?

Tags: c

```
void main()
{
    int x,y;
    scanf("%d", &x);   <-1
    y=(x>5?3:4);
    printf("%d",y); ->4
}
```

What is the use of: in `y=(x>5?3:4);` ?

Answer (score 4):

It is known as ternary operator. This:

```
y= (x>5 ? 3 : 4);
```

means if `x` is greater than 5, to `y` will be assigned the value `3`, otherwise (`x` is less or equal to 5) the value 4 will be assigned to `y`. That code is semantically the same as:

```
if(x > 5)
  y  = 3;
else 
  y = 4;
```

you can find a more in-depth explanation [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/conditional-or-ternary-operator-in-c-c/).

Answer (score 2):

> *"What is the use of ***:*** in y=(x>5?3:4); ?"*

`:` represents the shorthand version of the `else` clause of an `if-then-else` expression when using the C [ternary operator](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/c-ternary-operator/).  So in your example:

```
y = (x>5 ? 3 : 4);
```

The English expression could be stated as:

> *if* `x` is greater than `5`, *then* set `y` equal to `3`, ***else*** set
> `y` equal to `4`.

The traditional long version in C syntax would use the expression sequence:

```
if(x > 5)
{
    //true path
    y = 3;    
}
else
{
    //false path
    y = 4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a [ternary operator or conditional operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).